# How to get the contents from a webpage using Python?

Tags: python-3.x, basic-authentication

I've seen many similar questions here, and research keeps telling me about the requests and urllib modules, but nothing is working.

All I want is to connect to my private github repository and obtain the contents of the raw page of one of my files.

Whenever I try to authenticate, seemingly nothing happens, that is, doing `urlopen(url).read()`, or I just get a bad handshake error.

I've tried many basic combinations with urllib and requests, trying to create a session for authentication, and following the basic authentication section in the urllib package python doc, but no luck. Is there just a code template for doing connections like this?

Comment: Can you please post your code and the error your have?

Comment: GitHub gives access to raw files like so ``https://raw.githubusercontent.com/{user}/{repo}/{branch}/{file}``

Comment: @MichaelCara my code is just a mish mash mess of multiple 'examples' I've found online with no success. I'm assuming however you create a session/log into the github website would be pretty standardised by this point. I'm not interested in knowing where my mess of a code went wrong, only to produce different errors, I just want a solution. Thanks.